# How can I match a text for multiple patterns without scanning it multiple times?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to match multiple patterns in given input Strings, so the outcome would be a list containing all the substrings that match any of my predefined patterns:

```
String input = "Episode_NN 3_CD was_XX awesome_XX";

final Pattern ruleOne = Pattern.compile("(\\w*_NN\\s|\\w*_NNS\\s)+\\w*_CD");
final Pattern ruleTwo = Pattern.compile(ruleOne.pattern().concat(""));

Matcher matcher = ruleOne.matcher(input);

List<String> ent = new ArrayList<String>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    ent.add(matcher.group());
}
```

So do I have to add multiple Matchers? That would mean scanning the text multiple times, like so:

```
while (matcherOne.find() | matcherTwo.find() | ...) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Wrap your patterns in `(pattern1)|(pattern2)`.

Comment: Like this: `Matcher matcher = (ruleOne)|(ruleTwo).matcher(input);` ?

Comment: So where do I wrap them is my question, I guess :P

Comment: @Pete I believe aioobe meant `Pattern.compile("(pattern1)|(pattern2)").matcher(input)`. But be aware that pattern1 will be tested before pattern2 and if pattern1 will match some part of your text it will consume it which will prevent pattern2 from matching it. For instance for regex like `(fo)|(foo)` and string like `fooo` only `fo` part will match, not `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's that simple. Except you're better off using the [CONDITIONAL OR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) statement. This evaluates from left to right and if the first condition is true, it never evaluates the rest. It is made up of two bars  like so: `||`

```
while (matcherOne.find() || matcherTwo.find() || ...) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: "*Except the an OR statement is made up of two bars like so:* `||`" are you trying to say that `|` is not valid `OR` operator in Java and we must use `||`?

Comment: @Pshemo `|` is a bitwise operator. But here since it's boolean, it doesn't really make a difference from using `||`.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan "`|` is a bitwise operator" not quite. If `|` it is used to operate on integers it is *Integer Bitwise Operator*. If it is used to compare boolean values it is *Boolean Logical Operator*. "*it doesn't really make a difference from using `||`*" actually there is one big difference between boolean `|` and `||` and that is `||` is short-circuit which means if it can skip rest of calculations if it already knows the result like in case of `foo() || bar()` if `foo()` will return `true` `bar()` will not be executed because it can't change result. If we use `|` `bar()` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you can use several alternatives in 1 pattern (use alternation operator `|`):

```
\w*_NNS?\b|\w*_CD\b
```

Sample code

```
String input = "Episode_NN 3_CD was_XX awesome_XX";
final Pattern ruleOne = Pattern.compile("\\w*_NNS?\\b|\\w*_CD\\b");
Matcher matcher = ruleOne.matcher(input);

List<String> ent = new ArrayList<String>();

while (matcher.find()) {
  ent.add(matcher.group());
}
String[] arr = new String[ent.size()];
arr = ent.toArray(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/IwyLbn)

Output: `[Episode_NN, 3_CD]`

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need more assistance with the task?